# finding and replacing a part of data content in a file(javascript)

Tags: javascript, sorting, fs

I am trying to write a function that will read data from a file and replace a small part of it by something else without having to rewrite the data. For example if the data in the file is "a,b,c,d" I want to replace "b" with "e" without rewriting a c and d to the file. Can anyone help?I tried storing the content in an array using String.split(' ') and then replacing the desired chars but it didn't work (no errors in the node.js console).

This is the code i am using for reading from a file called file.txt and writing to a file called file2.txt. Now i want to replace a small part of the content from file.txt

```
fs.createWriteStream("file2.txt");
fs.readFile("file.txt", function read(err, data){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    content = data.toString();
    console.log(content);
    fs.writeFile("file2.txt",content , function(err){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript strings are immutable you cannot change "a,b,c,d" to "a,e,c,d" directly you need to create a new string.

If you will create a new string i think the best way is read the data [piece by piece](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) and change the character you need while reading the whole data. Then just write data to new file.

Comment: I see, so there is no way of only replacing a small part of the string

Comment: Yes strings can not change in js but you can create new one with a manupulate

Comment: ok thanks i just rewrote the whole file again using fs.writeFile();